# Reading Excel sheets in java

Tags: java, excel

I'm making a java program -using apache library- that reads from Excel file but the problem is, that I'm defining every sheet I want to open any Excel file & be able to choose any sheet as well as fill ComboBox with sheet name. (I'm using JComboBox to choose the sheet).

My attempt:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

int sheetNum = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
for(int i = 0; i < sheetNum; i++) {
    String sheetname = workbook.getSheetName(i);
    chooseSheetComboBox.addItem(sheetname);
}

int choosenSheet = chooseSheetComboBox.getSelectedIndex();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(choosenSheet);
```

Comment: `chooseSheetComboBox.getSelectedIndex()` will always return `-1`, since there's no event handling, and this line is directly excuted after the loop, normally no sheet is chosen

Comment: you'll need to add an ActionListener to your ComboBox and do the getSelectedIndex() from within that

Comment: @мυѕτавєւмo I thought I'll fill the combo box first so the sheet's name will appear, then let the user choose the sheet

Comment: `String selectedValue = chooseSheetComboBox.getSelectedValue().toString();` will return the string value of selected sheet. But you should have to use inside `event handler`.

Comment: @alhinai-hamed this's the problem that I'm facing, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an event handler over the items of the combo box, Just after filling it by the loop:

```
  chooseSheetComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                choosenSheet = chooseSheetComboBox.getSelectedIndex();
              XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(choosenSheet);
               // complete your logic, maybe call a method that takes XSSFSheet in parameters
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you explain more your code? I run the code but the combo box hasn't filled with any sheet name. (I'm new to java programming)

Comment: What I supposed is that your code fills that combo box, unless your excel file has no sheet, it is supposed to work and fill it

Comment: I don't have empty sheet, the combo box still not filled.

Comment: Ok @mona, can I see your code, and also an example of the excel file you are working with?

Comment: the same as you provided

Comment: I mean where did you add it in my code? I’m sorry for my silly question but I’m new to java I’m learning gui this week. If you code share the code that worked with you I’ll appreciate your help. Just share a screen shot of it.

Comment: as I said before, I have changed nothing and tried your code out and it worked for me.

Comment: I finally can see my combox filled, but when I choose the number then click it again to see the filled sheet name. I don't want this, I want when I choose the document the combobox filled automatically.